# samba4 vfs_audit + vfs_recycle not logging deletes

Tags: ubuntu, samba

I want to log all user deletes on samba shares. I noticed that when using vfs_audit and vfs_recycle together the deletes are not logged by samba. In the below config, deletes on [share1] are not logged, likely because the files are not "deleted" but rather moved to /data/share1/.recycle

All deletes are recorded on [share2] as one would expect.

Any way around this? I didn't see an option to log mv in the vfs_audit man page.

thanks.

```
[global]    
    audit:prefix = %u|%I|%m|%S
    audit:priority = notice
    audit:facility = LOCAL7
    vfs objects = audit
    audit:failure = none
    audit:success = mkdir rename unlink rmdir pwrite connect
[share1]
    recycle:repository = .recycle
    vfs objects = recycle
    path = /data/share1
    recycle:keeptree = yes
    recycle:versions = yes
[share2]
    path=/data/share2
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to achieve this. 
But I've tested a workaround, which maybe useful to your case:

**To "log" who has deleted a file**, you could modify the path of the recycle bin to a [.recycle/UserWhoDeletedTheFile] - replace the following in your config:

```
recycle:repository = .recycle
```

with the following:

```
recycle:repository = .recycle/%u
```

The above will create a folder in ".recycle" with the name of the user who deleted a file/folder.

**To "log" the time when a file/folder is deleted**, the recycle module has a function to change the mtime. Add the following to your config:

```
recycle:touch = yes
```

This changes the modify time of a file/folder to the time when it is deleted.

*NOTE: Keep in mind that when a folder is deleted, only the mtime of the folder itself is modified, not the contents', which may lead to some confusion.*

Comment: What is the difference between `recycle/%U` and `recycle/%u`?